# certbot script, for SSL renewal when running in a docker container, is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a set up a nginx webserver via docker compose. Everything (my spring boot app, the webserver and certbot) is running in a container. The site is reachable, everything works fine.

Now I want a script for auto renewal the SSL certificates from letsencrypt.
When running this command "docker compose run certbot renew --dry-run" from the directory where the docker-compose.yml is located, it works. When using this in a script it does not work.

Here are my files:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-app:
    image: XXX
    container_name: fridge-manager
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"  # Map container port 8080 to host port 8080
    environment:
      - MONGO_DB_URI=XXX
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network



  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"    
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - dhparam:/etc/ssl/certs
    depends_on:
      - my-app
    networks:
      - app-network



  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email XXX --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d XXX.de


volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/ben/services/views/
      o: bind
  dhparam:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/ben/services/dhparam/
      o: bind

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

ssl_renew.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

COMPOSE="/usr/local/bin/docker-compose --ansi never"
DOCKER="/usr/bin/docker"

cd /home/ben/services

$COMPOSE run certbot renew --dry-run

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    $COMPOSE restart webserver
else
    echo "SSL certificate renewal failed."
fi

$DOCKER system prune -af
```

sudo crontab -e:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/ben/services/ssl_renew.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

I am quite new to this whole dev ops thing. This is my first webserver setup.

Comment: Please include any error logs you may have encountered.